# Passing array as an argument: C and Java

Tags: java, c

Before I ask my question, I will note that I know:

1. In C, we can call a method  by value as well by reference
2. In Java, we can only call a method by value ( when we pass an Object, we are passing the value of the object reference not the object reference itself )
3. In C and Java context, there is a difference between pointers and reference.

Now to the question:

Consider an array:

```
arr = {1,2,3,4,5} //len =5
```

In C, I can do the following two things:

```
foo(arr, len);
bar (arr+ 2, len -2);
```

Function definitions:

```
foo(int *a, int l) {
  ...
  printf("%d", &a[0];  //prints 1
  ...
}

bar (int *a, int l){
  printf("%d", &a[0];  //prints 3
  ...
}
```

As we can see array a in function bar starts with the value 3, as it contains the address of arr[2](the original array). This is a neat way of passing arrays in C, if we  want to treat a sub-array as a new array with starting index 0.

I was wondering if same can be achieved in Java not withstanding that the following call has different meanings in C and Java:

```
foo(arr);
```

Comment: `2. In Java, we can only call a method by value` it's not true!

Comment: Both C and Java only have pass-by-value semantics. In C you can pass a pointer by value, and in Java you can pass a reference by value, but both are pass-by-value.

Comment: Your foo() and bar() functions are exactly the same. Why are you making a distinction in the example?

Comment: You can always do something like the following in java: foo(array, offset, length)

Comment: Don't Java APIs tend to use `arr, offset, length` to achieve that (passing a slice of an array as argument)?

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford, the difference in the way they are being called and hence the different outputs they print.

Comment: @futurenext110 The output is different because of the input. They're the same function; you should probably think of them that way.

Comment: @JonSkeet To be picky, that isn't entirely true in C. When you pass `type** var`, then you pass a reference-to-a-reference by value, yet `*var` is a reference.

Answer (score 4):

yes, just add a parameter `int off` or use the `IntBuffer` class.

```
void foo(int[] a,int off, int l) {
 ...
 System.out.printf("%d", a[off];  //prints 1
 ...
 ...
}

f(a,2,l);


void foo(IntBuffer a,int l){
   System.out.printf("%d",a.get(0));
}
IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.wrap(a,2,a.length-2);
foo(buffer,l);
```

Comment: this is a very common java pattern!

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about whether you can address the elements of the array by doing pointer arithmetic like in `arr + 2`, then the answer is no.

However, you can achieve the same effect by passing in the array and the position where you want start reading the array.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying structure of the array in java has an extra element at the head that indicates it's length. So your original array would be `{len, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` as stored by the JVM. This is done to keep java 'safe' from out of index operations on the array. This also makes it almost impossible to do pointer arithmetic in java.

To do something like this in java you would typically use some sort of `Buffer` class to wrap your array.

Answer (score 0):

Java lacks native slicing functions (as the implicit one you have in C regarding the start of the array or the explicit ones you have in a few modern languages) but it's easy to build your own class wrapping an array, an index and a length if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the same when you pass arrays in C and Java.

In Java, all that are passed for objects are references to them, namely pointers. In Java, you never say: A *a = new A(); you just write A a = new A(); The lack of * is the difference. Otherwise, A behaves exactly like a pointer.

Primitive variables are passed by value.

Comment: But in Java you can't call "bar (arr+ 2, len -2);"?

Comment: You don't slice arrays in Java, sadly. Also, arr + 2 uses a primitive notation based on what the dereferencing pointer type is. That's not true in Java.